# Mingw windowsXP application corefile (.dmp) debugging tool

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, crash, mingw

For an application written on C++ and compiled/built on mingw, I am facing issues in core file analysis. I have my application built/run on XP machine.

1. How do we save core file generated in the test bed of Windows XP? The application is delivered to user/test engineer and if the "users" gets the crash - how to save the crash file and send it across?
2. Can you suggest the best available debugger for this kind of set-up? I did go through Windbg32, coredumper.exe etc - but these depends on specific VC generated symbol file. And mingw used application cannot be used in lieu with Wingdb32.
3. Is there any specific compilation flag I need to use on mingw during application building - so that I can read all symbols from the core file - during the analysis.

Thanks in advance for advice. Any link on these material also would help a lot.